# Combing cells in excel where Identifier and date match

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have data that is formatted as so;

| Identifier | Date | Currency figure |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ID1 | 01/02/22 | 100 |
| ID1 | 01/02/22 | 99 |

And I'd like to transform that data so if Identifier and Date match in say Rows 2 & 3, then the new line in my new table on a sheet would be ID1 01/02/022 199

Answer (score 0):

Try this method:

**Identifier** column enter the formula:

```
=UNIQUE($A$2:$A$3)
```

**Date** column enter the formula:

```
=UNIQUE($B$2:$B$3)
```

**Currency** figure column enter the formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$3=F2)*(B2:B3=G2),$C$2:$C$3)
```

[image]